# How to create c# class with ability to serialize to dynamic json object (like datatables.net config)?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, datatables, json.net

I'm using datatables.net for ASP.NET MVC and I would like to create a class names DataTablesConfiguration that contains all properties of datatables.net. The purpose of this is instead config properties of datatables in View or JS file, I can config by setting properties of a DataTablesConfiguration object in server-side code, and then serialize the object to json object and pass into View. So all config of datatables would be done on server-side.

**Example:**

I can do like that to config datatables:

```
    DataTablesConfiguration config = new DataTablesConfiguration();
    config.ServerSide = true;
    config.Ajax.Url = "/Demo/LoadData";
    config.Columns.Add(new DataTablesColumn
            {
                Data = "CustomerID",
                AutoWidth = true,
                Header= "CustomerID",
                Name = "CustomerID"
            });
```

**The problem is:**
Datatables has many properties with dynamic type. Example:
**autoFill**:
Maybe this:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    autoFill: true
} );
```

But sometimes:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    autoFill: {
        alwaysAsk: true,
        columns: ':not(:last-child)'
    }
} );
And sometimes:
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    autoFill: {
        alwaysAsk: true,
        columns: [0,1,2],
        enable: true
    }
} );
```

**buttons**:
Maybe this:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'excel', 'pdf'
    ]
} );
```

But some time:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'copy',
            text: '<u>C</u>opy',
            key: {
                key: 'c',
                altKey: true
            },
            //and some other properties may appear here based on extend 
 property
        }
    ]
} );
```

I mean properties in datatables config is dynamic. So how to describe them by Class in C# code and able then serialize it to what datatables exactly wants to receive. 
I tried this:

```
public class DataTablesConfiguration
    {
        //Init default values base on datatables.net's reference
        public DataTablesConfiguration()
        {
            this.Buttons = new List<ButtonOption>();
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "buttons")]
        public ICollection<ButtonOption> Buttons { get; set; }

        public string GetJsonConfig()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }

public class ButtonOption
    {
        public ButtonOption(string extend, string text)
        {
            this.Extend = extend;
            this.Text = text;
        }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "extend")]
        public string Extend { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        //How can I define all other properties here
    }
```

But it seems to be not a good approach. Is there any better approach to make datatables could be configured on server-side code?